# Autoconvert site-internal-link-only answers to comments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, convert-to-comment, link-only-answers, automatic-edits

When an answer consisting solely of a link to elsewhere in the Stack Exchange universe is posted, it should be converted to a comment prefixed with "See: ".  Perhaps this could be widened to cover *any* single-link answer.

Some sort of rubric, perhaps

> Your answer consists solely of a
>   hyperlink, and will be posted as a
>   comment unless you add further
>   details.

could appear when the answer is being composed.

Comment: Think about new members who can't post comments yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now completed per the answer provided at

[Answer appears automatically converted as a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment/98955#98955)

> I posted an answer (pointing to another question already asked) but when I hit submit, I saw my answer appear as a comment to the question instead.

Answer (score 7):

My own inclination is, if the answer is solely a link to another Stack Overflow page (or same-site on the Stack Exchange network) the answerer should be prompted to post a *full* answer, explaining how that answer is applicable or may be amended/adapted to answer *this* question, or consider flagging the question as a possible duplicate of that question.

If the answer is a link to *another* website, outside of the Stack Exchange network, then I sincerely think that the answer should not be accepted for posting to the site, possibly until it's been reviewed and 'accepted' by a community moderator/>10K user. An explanatory note should be presented to the person trying to answer, but a link is not, nor should be considered, in most cases an **answer**.

Comment: What about questions that are asking for resources like, where's a good site that explains the basics of C#?