# Should we flag answers that only contain a link to another Stack Overflow answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, hyperlinks, answer-quality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do we do with answers that are just links to other Stack Overflow answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100532/what-do-we-do-with-answers-that-are-just-links-to-other-stack-overflow-answers)

There are many, many answers that simply contain a link to another Stack Overflow answer, with no additional context or information.

This topic has been discussed before, but in a broader context:

- [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)
- [Should I flag answers which contain only a link as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer)
- [Should there be a policy about 'One-Link-Only-Answers'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72000/should-there-be-a-policy-about-one-link-only-answers)

The answers for the questions above are good, but most of them are intended to solve the problem of links to external resources.

I feel like we can narrow the scope for this specific case and come to a concrete community decision. Stack Overflow-link-only answers, in my opinion, are more suitable as comments. They also sometimes indicate that the question is a potential duplicate.

There has been one suggestion for a solution, but it hasn't received much activity:

- [Autoconvert site-internal-link-only answers to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83912/autoconvert-site-internal-link-only-answers-to-comments)

Should answers **only** containing a link (or multiple links) to **other Stack Overflow answers** be flagged for conversion to a comment?

Comment: I'm also willing to accept that this may be treated as a duplicate of some of the questions I linked to. I just feel that those don't do a good enough job of addressing what we should do for internally linked answers.

Comment: Refer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72000/should-there-be-a-policy-about-one-link-only-answers

Comment: I think there should a feature to explicitly link to another question, as in Jira "this issue is related to". For many problems there is not one answer, you have to read many similar ones to get an understanding of a problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If other SO questions fully answer the question, it should be closed as a duplicate of one of those other questions.

If the linked questions don't fully answer the question at hand, then you're just dealing with a bad answer and the fact that it contains a link is incidental. Consider downvoting, leaving a comment asking the poster to expand their answer and/or explain how they think the link is relevant, or posting a better and more complete answer of your own.

Flagging for conversion to a comment is a valid option in the latter case, but whether or not the conversion will actually happen will be up to a moderator. Generally, anything that honestly attempts to answer the question (even if badly) counts as an answer and should not be converted. Downvotes, edits, and better answers are the correct ways to handle poor answers, including ones that contain only a link.

Comment: If it doesn't fully answer it, but provides good information, should it be flagged for migration to a comment?

Comment: @Rob if it doesn't fully answer it, you might consider either: a) downvoting it, b) posting your own answer that does fully answer it, or c) editing the answer to improve it

Comment: @Rob In addition to what Daniel said, you can also leave a comment asking the poster to explain how they think the linked answer is relevant and/or to expand on it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With your updates, I think it covers off what I'm asking. If a moderator steps in and answers authoritatively (about whether or not they'd deem such a flag valid/invalid), I may change the accepted answer.

Comment: @Rob For what it's worth, I'm a moderator on [Programmers.SE]. :)

Comment: @Anna - Ah, okay. I don't frequent [programmers.se] very much, so I didn't know. I will consider your statement as moderator-authoritative. Thanks! :)