# Can I post the link of a similar question in the answer?

Tags: discussion, support

If I solved some problem in some different question and somebody else post the same question, then can I post a link to my previous answer in the answer?

Comment: Alternately, [this one might be more suitable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100532/what-do-we-do-with-answers-that-are-just-links-to-other-stack-overflow-answers).

Comment: better way will be to post the link as a comment,it will help to solve your time to post a new answer instead of posting a link only answer

Comment: do't they see it as spam ?

Answer (score 4):

You should, in general, just mark the question as a duplicate if the same answer applies (select 'flag' underneath the post). You can then link the other question, or your answer, in a comment for quick reference for the OP.

Link-only answers are not appreciated, so if you decide to also answer the new question, you should at the very least copy the relevant parts of the answer, and change them to make them applicable to the specific new question being asked now, and perhaps link to the old answer then 'for more information' at the end.

Comment: marking as duplicate will discourage the user from posting in future . Might be he have more complex problem than i understand

Comment: @ashish: If you ***really, really, really, really, really, really*** think that this is a problem, you should open up a discussion about it.