# How should I handle link-only answers pointing to another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, answers, stack-exchange, link-only-answers

On Super User, I saw an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/524430/885) that points to an answer on Stack Overflow:

> `brew install wkhtmltopdf` fails.
>
> I documented on StackOverflow the correct way to install wkhtmltopdf
>   using Homebrew here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14043085/307308

How should I handle such an answer?

If it were pointing to another site on the same Stack Exchange, I'd look into whether the questions are duplicate of each other.

If it were pointing to a non Stack Exchange site, I'd flag the answer as link-only.

But what do I do in this scenario?

[What do we do with answers that are just links to other Stack Overflow answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100532/what-do-we-do-with-answers-that-are-just-links-to-other-stack-overflow-answers) only talks about links to another answer within the same Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 6):

I would ask or edit to quote the other answer, as any answer can be deleted by their owner, as such in my own opinion we should act like its an external's link that was wrote.

For the user expectation it's better too as when reading the question and answer, he will not have to click to load another question to see the actual answer.

Comment: and since SE answers are CC licenced anyway, there's no reason you can't do this with attribution