# Are answers which tell the OP to "contact my company's tech support" really "answers"?

Tags: discussion, flags

Generally these include a link, or even a phone number, which I suppose is somewhat useful, (until the company closes it's doors), but it's not really an answer to the question. Others others can't use the answer without making the phonecall as well.

One can argue that the OP could just go to said company's website for that, though the counter is that for *many* questions here on SO, the answer is already out there.

Should these be flagged as "Not an answer"?

1. Maybe you could contact our Support department? They can probably answer your question
2. That's my company, we would be glad to help you if...
3. etc...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a generalisation, yes they should be flagged.

What you describe is no different in principle to posting a link to an external resource because that place already has a code sample, or for whatever reason; regardless of the reason, the practice is still for the most part flawed and the behaviour should be tackled.

Flag away.

<sub>Note that this post ignores that such answers being given to a question is potentially indicative of this not being the ideal place for the question.</sub>

Comment: For reference on "link only posts" see this question and those it links to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95491/should-we-flag-answers-that-only-contain-a-link-to-another-so-answer . Thanks for drawing the analogy.