# Unusual behaviour from new user (affiliated with the BIS)

Tags: discussion, behavior, self-promotion

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1037890/michael?tab=activity) has been on an answering/editing spree for the past hour, and each and every answer/edit contains a paragraph along the lines of:

> Check out the BIS web site at www.bis.doc.gov/encryption or call the help desk at 202-482-0707 if you want to discuss the particulars of your app.

Most of the suggested edits are easy calls for "invalid edit" since it attempts to comment on the post, but what about answers?

At a quick glance, some of the answers seem kinda legit (apart from the *spammy* paragraph).

What do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are answers which tell the OP to "contact my company's tech support" really "answers"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110527/are-answers-which-tell-the-op-to-contact-my-companys-tech-support-really-ans)

Comment: He is linking to a government website. Most unusual "spam".

Comment: Unusual indeed hence this post. Had it been a from a normal source I'd flag/reject without hesitation.

Comment: Looks like the account has been temporarily suspended.

Comment: See my answer and the comments below.

Comment: Ahh.. I missed the last comment. That answers my curiosity as to whether he trigger an auto-suspension or if it was imposed by a mod.

Comment: The `.gov` website wasn't spam. I think this was a government employee that was just trying to be helpful. BIS is the US Bureau of Industry And Security, which is there to help people who have questions regarding export restrictions.

Comment: I agree, hence my cautious use of the term spam (in quotes). I know not how to deal with unusual behaviour from a legit organisation and so I turned to the wisdom Meta. I'm actually now feeling guilty over his suspension. Well, just a bit.

Comment: And if you go to the URL in his profile it times out. use [www.bis.doc.gov](http://www.bis.doc.gov/) instead (I am not affiliated with the BIS :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I sent him a message.  I didn't delete the answers, because they do appear to have some value, but I did ask him to add his affiliation to his profile and all of the answers he posted.

Comment: Did your message mention the [suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1037890/michael?tab=activity#page_1-filter_suggestions) which inserted the message into other people's answers?

Comment: @Kevin: No, it didn't.  Feel free to reject those.

Comment: The suggested edits seemed like abuse that required (requires) a mod message.  The answers were less of a problem than editing this "This is wrong, call me" disclaimer into other answers, if you ask me.

Comment: I agree with @KevinVermeer. I'm willing to ascribe this to a lack of understanding (that his content should have been posted as a fully-formed answer rather than as an edit to an existing answer; his rep is too low to comment) rather than abuse. Either way, he still needs to be aware.

Comment: @KevinVermeer: I sent him another message about the suggested edits, and suspended his account for 7 days. I guess he'll have to wait that long to insert his affiliations. :P

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a government employee that just didn't understand how things work.

Comment: Ouch, seven days?  You're a hardcore pipe hittin' ... fella.

Comment: @Tim ahahahaha! The revenge of the citizen.

Comment: @Pekka Yeah, but export restrictions are _super freaking hard_ to understand, and the person was adding valuable breadcrumbs (albeit in the wrong way).

Comment: @Tim: It's just 7 days. He probably won't even visit the site during that time.

Comment: @Tim I agree. I think 7 days is a bit much, this was clearly posted with helpful intentions. Maybe remove it if he reacts?

Comment: @Tim: I suspended for the suggested edits, not for the spamming. He was [defacing existing posts](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1037890/michael?tab=activity#page_1-filter_suggestions) with his message.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, that had to stop, and they didn't respond to my earlier comment. If they reply to the mod message, maybe we can get the guy on the phone and let them know how to do it properly.

Comment: @Robert ah, fair enough, hadn't seen those edits.

Answer (score 6):

The website is authentic, and the [number checks out](http://www.bis.doc.gov/encryption/technologycontacts.htm), so he's hardly self promoting something.

Regardless, it appears *out of place* to me on SO ("spam").

Additionally, he's got his [address](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1037890/michael?tab=stats) set to http://www.bis.doc.gov/encryption, so I get the feeling he's only here to promote it :P

There's a chance he'll realise he's doing something wrong from his rejected edits, and stop doing so; otherwise there might be a need for a mod to send a polite reminder :P

Comment: "Additionally, he's got his address set to http://www.bis.doc.gov/encryption, so I get the feeling he's only here to promote it " ... Mods asked him to add his affiliation to his profile.

Comment: @eternalseptember: He'd already had it set that way *before* Robert contacted him.