# Editing Mistakes OR closing down a potential useful anwer? by the moderators

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I wanted to know from the moderators - if someone answers a question and the answer potential may be useful to the one who asked the question and for that matter anyone who ever comes across to that question.

**But** answer is a set of links from Stackoverflow, is the moderators duty to **edit** the question or **delete** it?

The reason why I am saying this is

Today I answered a question:

- [How to hide any row in gridview based on any value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741150/how-to-hide-any-row-in-gridview-based-on-any-value)

[image]

My answer was deleted by the moderator instead of editing or atleast letting me or someone edit the answer

The moderator could have let me edit it at least

Comment: The very reason the the site has 'edit' for anybodies answer or question is to **improve** the answer or atleast tell to **improve**

Comment: Moderators aren't responsible for hand-holding. Especially when you've got enough rep to flag or comment where it would have been more appropriate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should we flag answers that only contain a link to another SO answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95491/should-we-flag-answers-that-only-contain-a-link-to-another-so-answer)

Comment: There's still an edit link on the answer. What makes you think it won't work?

Answer (score 15):

I deleted it because it was nothing more than list of links to other Stack Overflow questions, and as I stated in my comment under your answer, such lists of links are not **answers**. I didn't see how it could have been edited into something that would **answer the actual question**.

You can still edit your answer after it's deleted, though, since it'll still be visible to you, regardless of whether it was deleted by yourself or a moderator. Go right ahead and edit it, and I'll see if it's worth reinstating. But if you simply want to provide a list of links, I suggest posting a comment instead. Answers have to actively answer a question.

Comment: Ok, i agree it was a bunch of links, that i have put there, but i as a moderator u did what was correct according to you for the site, in your comment your mentioned "give them more meaningful titles", so im asking you knew the answer required meaning titles than i think you could have let me edit it with your comment or atleast edited yourself.

Comment: Well, that was just a side note, and not the main reason why I deleted it.

Comment: ok, but were the links unhelpful in any way?

Comment: Again, it's hard to tell. In retrospect I could have converted it to a comment on your behalf, but I chose to delete it as I imagine it'll be easier and cleaner if you started writing a new comment or answer instead.

Comment: @PresleyDias I don't think the links were *harmful* in any way, but they weren't particularly helpful either.  When someone writes their question on Stack Overflow they get a list of potentially related posts to look through.  You can assume they're already seen a list of links to other questions on SO.  It would be better if you find one answer that explicitly answers the question being asked, link to it, and explain *why* it answers the question.

Comment: ok, but again "I imagine it'll be easier and cleaner" i agree, it would have been, but what im saying is why wasnt i given time for editing (enough time)..your a experienced user ,should have let a child like me grow by telling to edit

Comment: Deletion isn't as permanent as it looks. I can always undelete it at any time. Plus, like I said, you can edit your own answer whether or not it was deleted and by whom.